# Disable menuitem when binded viewmodel is null

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

So I have a `MenuItem` which is binded to an ActiveDocument.

```
<MenuItem Header="Save File" Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.SaveCommand}"/>
```

Enable/Disable is set by the ViewModel:

```
private bool CanSave(object parameter)
{
    return IsDirty;
}
```

How can I make the MenuItem default to disabled when I don't have an ActiveDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a trigger that sets the `IsEnabled` property of the `MenuItem` to `false` whenever the `Command` property returns a `null` reference:

```
<MenuItem Header="Save File" Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.SaveCommand}">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Command" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```